# How to install and use pandastable ? 'griddata' missing

Tags: python-3.x

Import error occurs when I execute `from pandastable import Table`.
What should I do?

I would like to use pandastable. I installed it (0.12.0) then following the instruction pandastable.pdf, I copied a code below to an editor and saved, then executed.

```
from tkinter import * 
from pandastable import Table 

pt = Table(parent)
pt.show()
```

Then error occurred:

> cannot import name 'griddata' from 'matplotlib.mlab'"
>    occurred at "from matplotlib.mlab import griddata".
>
> matplotlib version is 3.1.0 but I could not find 'griddata' in mlab.py.

Answer (score 4):

`griddata` has been [removed](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#matplotlib-mlab-removals) from matplotlib 3.1.

use [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)

Comment: The original post is quite dated, but this is one of the first pages to appear when searching for `"pylab" "ImportError" "griddata"`